# Serve laravel dev on local or public IP

Tags: laravel, server, artisan-serve

I had this working a while ago but it stopped for some reason.

What I want is to access the dev serve on LAN or public IP.

I could do it by serving `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

`ifconfig` sais `inet 192.168.0.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255`

I would port forward `192.168.0.150` on port `8000` and voila, I could connect on my phone from `http://192.168.0.150:8000` or the `publicIP:8000`. Now none work.

If I try `http://192.168.0.150:8000` on the PC that I serve, it works, but on my phone connected to the WiFi it sais `Could not connect to the server. NSURLErrorDomain`

What changes I did in the past days was to remove apache2 and install nginx, but I don't think it had anything to do with artisan.

Comment: I presume it's your network configuration that caused that

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Have not changed anything and the firewall sais disabled  `sudo ufw status Status: inactive`

Comment: Are you sure your local IP did not change? This has nothing to do with Laravel

Comment: @matiaslauriti the output of ifconfig is in the question, that's the ip

Answer (score 0):

If you can load your application directly (on localhost) with your LAN IP, then this seems not to be a Laravel issue.

Instead, check your firewall config. Make sure the port `8000` is opened on the local firewall for inbound traffic.

And it is highly **not** recommended to open a port in your router to access the application to the WAN / internet.

Comment: Firewall looks disabled: sudo ufw status Status: inactive

Comment: Any firewalls in your network that are possibly separating your mobile phone's network from the one of your development machine?

Comment: No, I have a router and that's it, it worked before and I have not made any changes to it, so it must be from the PC.

Comment: If you have another PC, you can try with a tool like nmap or "Advanced Port Scanner" to check if the port is indeed open.